# Storing parameter from JavaScript in Android

Tags: javascript, android, parameter-passing

I have a JavascriptInterface and a setter/getter in my Android code:

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new AccessibleMethods(), "Android");

private class AccessibleMethods {
    private boolean isWorking;
    public void setIsWorking(boolean working)
    {
        this.isWorking = working;
        // A toast message here of this.isWorking displays true
    }
    public boolean getIsWorking()
    {
        return this.isWorking;
    }
}
```

In my JavaScript code I call the function:

```
Android.setIsWorking(true);
```

But when I try to access isWorking in Java in another method or outside the class, it doesn't have the correct value.

```
AccessibleMethods methods = new AccessibleMethods();
methods.getIsWorking(); // returns wrong or no value
```

I need this for accessing a JavaScript variable onKeyDown.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share the data passed from the JavaScript, you should use the same instance of the object across the method calls, or use an instance variable.

```
private AccessibleMethods methods = new AccessibleMethods();
//... 
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(methods, "Android");
//..
boolean isWorking = methods.getIsWorking();
```

Comment: If you think this can help anyone else, retain this; otherwise, you are free to delete it.